# How to enforce ORDER BY when using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT itemId, parentId, value FROM item ORDER BY value DESC
```

which correctly returns:

```
+--------+------------------+
| itemId | parentId | value |
+--------+------------------+
|      1 |        5 |   500 |
|      4 |        1 |   500 |
|      2 |        5 |    10 |
|      5 |        1 |    10 |
|      3 |        5 |     0 |
|      6 |        1 |     0 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I tried adding "GROUP BY parentId", but this seems to pick two random items, ignoring the ORDER BY clause:

```
+--------+------------------+
| itemId | parentId | value |
+--------+------------------+
|      2 |        5 |    10 |
|      6 |        1 |     0 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

What SQL should I use to return only the item with the highest value for each parentId?:

```
+--------+------------------+
| itemId | parentId | value |
+--------+------------------+
|      1 |        5 |   500 |
|      4 |        1 |   500 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: select itemId, parentId, max(value) as val from item group by parentId order by val desc

Comment: This would give me results like [itemId=2, parentId=5, value=10, val=500]. I need to return the correct itemId associated with the highest value, not just the highest value itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `itemId`, only select it if its `value` is the `MAX` of its `parentId`:

```
SELECT itemId, parentId, value
FROM item i
WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) 
               FROM item t 
               WHERE t.parentId = i.parentId)
```

Which returns:

```
| ITEMID | PARENTID | VALUE |
-----------------------------
|      1 |        5 |   500 |
|      4 |        1 |   500 |
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd8e/2)**.

Comment: Yes this works! I had to add GROUP BY for the case where two itemIds have the same parentId and value (I only want one), and ORDER BY to maintain that the biggest value come first no matter what parentId.